# Display different text depending on other text on page

Tags: javascript

Background.
I use an LMS that has an automatic translator in it based off a user field.
the System also allows me to add HTML, CSS and Javascript to add my own elements / reskin the system. BUT it doesn't automatically translate these (for good reasons.)

I have users in English and French. And I have a banner that needs to include some text on it.

I would like to show the text in either English or French, based on something.
the HTML language tag always stays as English - so I ruled that out.

So I was thinking of trying to base it off the Homepage Name. Which gets translated by the automatic translator.

Essentially I want to say if the page has Home as the page name then show the English text, or If the page has Accuiel then show the french text.

HTML

```
<div id="English">
<div class="main_hero container">
<div class="hero_content">
<h1 class="hero_h1">Test English</h1>
</div>

<div id="French">
<div class="main_hero container">
<div class="hero_content">
<h1 class="hero_h1">Test French</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript - Referencing the HTML.

```
var str = "Home";
var str = "Accueil";
if (str = Home) {
document.getElementById("English");
}
if (str = Accueil) {
 document.getElementById("French");
}
```

All help appreciated.
Cam

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? What text are you trying to detect, and what do you want to show if either are the case. Also why are you trying to do this? Are these your HTML pages?

Comment: @LukeStorry Thanks - I've added some more detail. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: If you're already depending on auto-translation, why not let the text you're generating be auto-trnslated also?

Comment: @LukeStorry The auto-translate doesn't work that way. It only translates the system generated text. It excludes anything else. There's a reason behind this, but it's not worth explaining here. It's just a limitation in regards to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both divs, with the english one shown, and the french one with a `display: none;` css style.

Then in your js, get the contents of that test element, and if it is accueil then switch the display properties:

```
let str = document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML;
if (str == "Accueil") {
    document.getElementById("English").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("French").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke. This currently doesn't work.  I've been able to identify the ID of the element that the switch is based off as id="pageTitle". If the contents of this H1 is home, then it needs to show the English. If it's Accueil, then it needs to show the french. Really appreciate your time!

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you tried the above, with that id changed? Have you tried with a `console.log(str)` to check whether it's picking up the string correctly? Can you check the `display: none;` and see if it's being toggled?

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm still a bit new to JS. I've tried the above with the ID changed. I'm getting a break in the console showing nothing with the {console.log(str);} and I also tried {console.log(str.innerhtml);} This gave me undefined in the console. I've checked the display:none and this is working as intended. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: If it is returning blank from the log, does that element with that id definitely have contents? What about `console.log(document.getElementById("pageTitle"))`?

Comment: The console log returns: `<h1 class="fd-shellbar__title mb-0  mt-0" id="pageTitle">Accueil</h1>`

Comment: Just FYI - I'm 99% certain the JS loads after the rest of the HTML. However, to check this I also wrapped the coed in a `window.onload = function ()`. With the same result. It still looks like it's getting hung up on the `if (str == "Accueil")`

Comment: So that console log returns the Element, so it is selecting correctly. What about `console.log(document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML)`?

Comment: I get two different things. 1. If I place `console.log(document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML)
` in the JS area on system - It doesn't return anything in the space at the top of the console where it should. It shows the reference on the side, but is blank at the top. 2. However if I put it directly into the console, it shows home.

Comment: What about if you place it in the `window.onload = function`?

Comment: Ok. I've been able to get it to work by referencing an ID that wasn't a H1 element. Instead I had to reference an Id that was in a link element. So including the `window.onload = fucntion`. Really appreciate all your help !!!!